# Maven clean stop/stuck at certain point

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have maven installed and it worked well before but now Maven clean stop/stuck at certain point . I have tried restarting eclipse but doesn't seem to work.

Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model 
for com.sony.hrportal:hrportal:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' 
must be unique: org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar -> duplicate declaration 
of version 3.2.5.RELEASE @ line 245, column 15
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' 
must be unique: com.sun.el:el-ri:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 1.0 
@ line 291, column 15
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' 
must be unique: org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar -> duplicate declaration of 
version 3.11 @ line 350, column 15
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they 
threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support 
building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         

[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building hrportal Maven Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ hrportal ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\Divagar_Workspace\hrportal\target
```

Comment: are you sure there's no currently running process using either that folder or a file there-in?

Comment: @Stultuske There is no other process running. I have imported only this project in eclipse. before it was working fine please let me know possible solution

Comment: I don't necessarily mean in your IDE. You might have windows explorer open on that directory, or notepad somewhere.

Comment: In any case, Eclipse Luna is a very old version, you'll have much trouble to find support for this version. You should consider upgrading to Oxygen.

Comment: can you try `mvn clean` on command line ? before that `right click on project > Maven > Update project `

Comment: Tried deleting by hand the target directory?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting eclipse local history , indexes and temp files solved the issue.